# water pressure from icemaker water line to fridge is reduced

Tags: plumbing

we replaced our fridge and after connecting the line the water pressure to my 
faucet which was beyond the saddle valve was cut in half.   we changed the saddle valve and after that the pressure changed.  the shower and the toilet are still at good levels. what happened?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a small pipe the saddle may be partially obstructing the water flow. If you have copper, pex, or PVC plumbing it would not be hard to cut the pipe install a T and fit a 1/4" adapter or 3/8" depending on the size to your frige then you will not have a pressure reduction and in a few years (when the saddle would fail) you prevented the failure from happening.

Comment: You should do this anyway. We went a year in a new home with very poor water flow to the refrigerator dispenser. The original owner had already replaced one saddle valve that had crusted shut with another one next to it. I did as Ed is suggesting and the flow to the frig tripled. It's worth the small time and expense for sure.

Comment: Also, saddle valves are generally terrible. They are not really "valves" so much as lazy ways of installing a T. Once you open and close a few times, they start to leak. If they haven't been operated in a couple years, they often won't close properly. There's really no redeeming qualities other than they often come free with appliances, and are slightly easier to install than a proper T + valve.